# Conversion from String to Date type error in SSRS report

Tags: date, reporting-services, colors, ssrs-2008, expression

I am designing a report and changed Font Colour of Date parameter to show as Red font if it is "Good" so, I am using this expression for Color property:

```
=IIF(Fields!Assignment_Date.Value="Good", "Black", "Red")
```

but this gives me error while executing:

```
rsRunTimeErrorInExpression: The Color expression for the text run Assignment_Date.Paragraph[0].TextRuns[0] contains an error: Conversion from string "Good" to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

Let me know if I can achieve this in SSRS.

Thanks,
Aruna

Comment: You are comparing a date type i.e. `2016-01-18` against `Good` string. You cannot compare different data types. What is the rule to define a date as Good?

Comment: If Assignment Date < Target Date

Comment: Is Target Date a field in your dataset?